# Selecting best fit combination of Multiple Collections based on a Value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a .net core web application for our employees to use to match products to a customer based on a balance that they enter in.  There are 5 types of products. Product 1 would have to be included in every bundle as the main product. The other 4 products would be bundled in with as many as possible based on that value.    But Product 1 also has multiple different price points. So lets say the customer can afford the highest price point of product 1 but only 2 addons. I would need it to drop to the next value of Product 1 and add every addon etc. Any guidance someone could give me would really help.

Comment: What does "as many as possible" mean? Can you have multiples of any product in a bundle? In general, subtract the minimum product 1, subtract the other products minimum first, use any balance left to raise product 1 class tier.

Comment: So product 1 has many different price points so Product 1 would always be included in every bundle as the main product. And from each of the other products there would only ever be one of each.

Comment: Is there a priority on the products, or is the priority including as many as possible, up to 4? And if you include as many as possible, is there a priority on higher pricing e.g. is it preferred to have a more expensive type 2 than type 3 or does it matter?

Comment: yes so Product 2 would be weighted higher then Product 3 and Product 3 would be weighted higher then Product 4 etc.

Comment: And if you have all 5 products (or 4 or 3) and there is balance left over, is it better to get a higher Prod1, or higher Prod2, or what?

Comment: It would be best to get a higher value of Product 1. The other products rarely have multiple.

Comment: "rarely have multiple" (sic) means they might as well always have multiple where programming is concerned. And after you get a higher value of Product1, then presumably highest Prod2/3/4/5 of the highest count matches of 2/3/4/5.

Comment: Yea that's how it would work I have it working with a giant foreach loop right now but its pretty ugly and will be very hard to maintain. But yes it would need to select from the highest valued product available based on prioritys when available.

Comment: I added an answer. I won't say it is better than a giant `foreach` loop - if you had large quantities of Product Types 2-5, the `AddOnCombos` generated could use up an excessive amount of memory.

Comment: In addition, because my answer is Combinations/Cartesian Product based, it tries every possible match. It should be possible to short circuit certain match possibilities if using multiple loops (e.g. if cheapest Prod 2+3+4 is too much, adding Prod 5 will never work).

Comment: This was perfect thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have a table of `Products` that have `Type` and `Price`.

You can device the `Products` into those of `Type` 1 and the rest:

```
var Prod1 = Products.Where(p => p.Type == 1);
var ProdNot1 = Products.Where(p => p.Type != 1);
```

Using some extension methods, you can create all possible combinations of non-type 1 products (if you are pulling from a database, you will have to do this in memory):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k) {
    return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
      elements.SelectMany((e, i) =>
        elements.Skip(i + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat(c)));
}
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> AllCombinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements) => Enumerable.Range(1, elements.Count()).SelectMany(k => elements.Combinations(k));

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) {
    var emptyProduct = Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsSingleton();
    return sequences.Aggregate(
      emptyProduct,
      (accumulator, sequence) =>
        from accseq in accumulator
        from item in sequence
        select accseq.Append(item));
}
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProductWithEmpties<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) =>
    sequences.AllCombinations().SelectMany(s => s.CartesianProduct());
```

Now you can compute the `AddOnCombos`:

```
var AddOnCombos = ProdNot1.GroupBy(p => p.Type)
                          .CartesianProductWithEmpties()
                          .Select(tpc => new { Products = tpc, Price = tpc.Sum(p => p.Price), Types = tpc.Sum(p => p.Type) });
```

Using the minimally priced Type 1 product:

```
var minPriceProd1 = Prod1.MinBy(p => p.Price);
```

You can take the `CustBal` and guess how much budget you have for add-on products:

```
var CustBal = 375;
var nonProd1BalGuess = CustBal - minPriceProd1.Price;
```

Then you can guess which add-on combo will work, maximizing count of types, prioritizing lower types and taking the minimum price:

```
var nonProd1Guess = AddOnCombos.Where(aoc => aoc.Price <= nonProd1BalGuess)
                           .OrderByDescending(aoc => aoc.Products.Count())
                           .ThenBy(aoc => aoc.Types)
                           .ThenBy(aoc => aoc.Price)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Using the add-on guess, you can guess the budget remaining for getting a higher priced product of Type 1:

```
var allProdBalGuess = nonProd1BalGuess - (nonProd1Guess?.Price ?? 0);
```

Then compute the final product of Type 1 and how much remains for add-on products:

```
var finalProd1 = Prod1.Where(p => p.Price <= minPriceProd1.Price + allProdBalGuess).OrderByDescending(p => p.Price).First();
var nonProd1Bal = CustBal - finalProd1.Price;
```

Then find the best add-on combination:

```
var nonProd1 = AddOnCombos.Where(aoc => aoc.Price <= nonProd1Bal)
                           .OrderByDescending(aoc => aoc.Products.Count())
                           .ThenBy(aoc => aoc.Types)
                           .ThenByDescending(aoc => aoc.Price)
                           .ThenByDescending(aoc => Enumerable.Range(2, 5).Select(t => aoc.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == t)?.Price ?? 0), new SeqCompare<double>())
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

To give proper precedence to spending more budget on lower `Type` products, you need some extensions to compare the sequences of prices:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static int SeqCompareTo<T>(this IEnumerable<T> s1, IEnumerable<T> s2) => SequenceCompare(s1, s2);

    public static int SequenceCompare<T>(IEnumerable<T> source1, IEnumerable<T> source2) {
        // You could add an overload with this as a parameter
        IComparer<T> elementComparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
        using (IEnumerator<T> iterator1 = source1.GetEnumerator())
        using (IEnumerator<T> iterator2 = source2.GetEnumerator()) {
            while (true) {
                bool next1 = iterator1.MoveNext();
                bool next2 = iterator2.MoveNext();
                if (!next1 && !next2) // Both sequences finished
                    return 0;
                if (!next1) // Only the first sequence has finished
                    return -1;
                if (!next2) // Only the second sequence has finished
                    return 1;
                // Both are still going, compare current elements
                int comparison = elementComparer.Compare(iterator1.Current,
                                                         iterator2.Current);
                // If elements are non-equal, we're done
                if (comparison != 0)
                    return comparison;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SeqCompare<T> : IComparer<IEnumerable<T>> {
    public int Compare(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y) => x.SeqCompareTo(y);
}
```